# Why do I lose reputation when I vote up an answer?

Tags: support, reputation, up-votes

Why do I lose reputation when I vote up an answer?

Comment: Can you give more information? When did this happen, and where? Exactly what steps did you take, and what was the result?

Comment: Why was this originally tagged "organization"? That makes no sense.

Comment: @26 it does, if an organization of Arch-Nemeses is behind it.

Comment: Because you're giving reputation and rep is like money: a trading coin... **not**!

Answer (score 10):

You lose reputation when you downvote and not for upvoting

Or if somebody has downvoted your question or answer.

Or if you're hallucinating.

Or if you have been transported (accidentally or by your nemesis) to the bizarro universe.

Comment: What would we do without Welbog?